# Eclipse Package Explorer no longer collapsible

Tags: eclipse

**Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)**

Very straight-forward question - to my surprise I could not find an answer on here, or elsewhere.

This is what I see in my Eclipse IDE:
[image: Collapsible]

This is what I have seen until recently (**circled in green**):
[image: Collapsible]
(Yes - this image is not showing *package* explorer, this is cut from a random internet search pic)

How do I make the Package Explorer collapsible again?
Needing to fully close it for space, and then open it again later is a big pain.

Comment: eclipse oxygen for windows here, I have the collapse icon for the package explorer, what version are you using?

Comment: Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2), I'll add this to the question, thanks.

Comment: I have Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) for windows too. It has the collapse button. You could update to a newer version.

Comment: Did you try a reset? Window → Reset perspective...

Comment: @DPM - I've always had the collapse button until the last few hours, I don't know what happened, it isn't a feature missing from this version.

Comment: @MySimpleMind, resetting the whole perspective did work, thanks for that, the button is back. I don't think its the cleanest answer to my question though, so I guess I'll leave the question open just in case someone knows exactly what caused it, and how to directly address it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If someone get the same problem, what I know so far is the reset perspective solution...

> Window → Perspective -> Reset perspective...

**This will save you many hours, believe me**!

You can also do the reset, by right click the icon of the perspective type.

Option 1. Using the Window menu.

[image]

Option 2. Right click the perspective icon

[image]

(You might need to customize your perspective if you configured own settings, the reset perspective does not damage your workspace! See customize perspective to get an idea of what the settings are.)